# how does electron access lower level system capacities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

i have installed the electron-quick-start package and npm started it, it worked! now i am wondering how it actually gets access to system capacities. by 'require("electron")', node reads electron/index.js which reads asynchronously path.txt file that points to the binary electron.app/Contens/MacOS/electron, then, node knows the path, node_modules/electron/dist/electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron, which is a binary executable file, and, afterwards, how does electron gets started and provide maybe to node, system level capacities?

Comment: Electron has system level capacities because NodeJS has it.
What makes javascript limited on the browser side is the fact that browser limit what you can do by creating a sandbox with your code.

Comment: I read C++ addons of Node.JS refs and realized that node can reuire compiled .cc binary file as modules.